# gnuplot, check if a function exist (defined)

Tags: gnuplot

[This](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node60.html) document demonstrates how one can check if a variable has been previously defined in a gnuplot script.

The example from the doc:

```
a = 10
if (exists("a")) print "a is defined"
if (!exists("b")) print "b is not defined"
```

However, is it possible to check if a function has been previously defined?

In other words, is there a way to do the following:

```
f(x) = 2*x 
if (exist("f(x)") print "Function is defined"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every user-defined function is available as special variable with prefix `GPFUN_`:

```
f(x) = 2*x
show variables GPFUN
```

prints

```
Variables beginning with GPFUN:
        GPFUN_f = "f(x) = 2+x"
```

So you can check for the function with

```
f(x) = 2*x 
if (exist("GPFUN_f") print "Function f is defined"
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that!

Comment: This is also useful to print or access the definition of a function in gnuplot, e.g. `print GPFUN_f`. Just so others might find this when googling such keywords.